# REGEX: needed in php

Tags: php, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "title": "test2",
        "json_query": {
            "condition": "AND",
            "rules": [{
                "id": "event",
                "field": "event",
                "type": "string",
                "operator": "equal",
                "value": "signup"
            }, {
                "condition": "AND",
                "rules": [{
                    "id": "event",
                    "field": "event",
                    "type": "string",
                    "operator": "equal",
                    "value": "signup"
                }, {
                    "condition": "AND",
                    "rules": [{
                        "id": "kwd",
                        "field": "kwd",
                        "type": "string",
                        "operator": "equal",
                        "value": "epub"
                    }]
                }]
            }, {
                "id": "kwd",
                "field": "kwd",
                "type": "string",
                "operator": "equal",
                "value": "arts"
            }, {
                "condition": "AND",
                "rules": [{
                    "id": "kwd",
                    "field": "kwd",
                    "type": "string",
                    "operator": "equal",
                    "value": "automotive"
                }, {
                    "condition": "AND",
                    "rules": [{
                        "id": "kwd",
                        "field": "kwd",
                        "type": "string",
                        "operator": "equal",
                        "value": "books"
                    }, {
                        "condition": "AND",
                        "rules": [{
                            "id": "kwd",
                            "field": "kwd",
                            "type": "string",
                            "operator": "equal",
                            "value": "business"
                        }, {
                            "condition": "AND",
                            "rules": [{
                                "id": "kwd",
                                "field": "kwd",
                                "type": "string",
                                "operator": "equal",
                                "value": "books"
                            }]
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

This is my string and i need the regex which will get all id with its value

eg: "id" : "event", "id" : "event", "id" : "kwd", "id" : "kwd"

means every occurrence, so i can replace or add a unique value to id

NOTE:- I dont want to make an array, dont want to do with loop,

finding possibility to replace with preg_match or any other regex method.

Comment: Don't use a regex for parsing JSON. There are [functions for this](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php).

Comment: use `json_decode()`and convert it to php array. do whatever you want and then convert back to json using `json_encode()`. BTW i am not a down-voter at all

Comment: If i want to do that i did not ask this

Comment: and you guyz why downwote this

Comment: This question deserves answers that show as much effort as you expended when you wrote that question, which is **zero**. Please take some time to complete the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and especially [ask] before posting your next question here.

Answer (score -1):

I got my answer myself:

preg_match_all('/"id":"(.*)",/U', $json, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

print_r($matches); die;

Comment: You ask a question and don't even take advice from what people are saying in the comments? See [#1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648873/regex-needed-in-php#comment72423774_42648873) and [#2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648873/regex-needed-in-php#comment72423805_42648873). **Don't** use regex for this.

Comment: everyone do this thing by converting it into array , my motive is only  to use the regex in string.